# Add and remove functionality in VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am looking for an add and removal functionality from one tab to another tab for a single single element in the list.
I have tried this with dialog box but it is giving me different result

```
  <td class="text-xs-left">
        <v-edit-dialog
           @open="temp = props.item.values"                                           
           large
           lazy>
        <div v-for="value in props.item.values">{{value}}</div>
         <div slot="input" class="mt-3 title">Update Iron</div>
        <v-text-field
         slot="input"
          label=""
        v-model="temp"
        single-line
        counter
        autofocus
        ></v-text-field>
        </v-edit-dialog>

        </td>
```

Now in the datatable col it give me the values like this :-

> 590380500

but I want like this:-

590
380
500
and when I open dialog box it gives me value like this

> 590,380,500

but I only want to add and remove one value and not all
for example:- if I select 590 so in dialog box it should show only 580.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have half solved it but still only one problem remain that values are not showing in a different line but in a single line

```
 <td class="text-xs-left">
    <v-edit-dialog
      v-for="value in props.item.values"
       @open="temp = props.item.values"                                           
       large
       lazy>
    <div>{{value}}</div>
     <div slot="input" class="mt-3 title">Update Iron</div>
    <v-text-field
     slot="input"
      label=""
    v-model="temp"
    single-line
    counter
    autofocus
    ></v-text-field>
    </v-edit-dialog>

    </td>
```

Now able to click the individual entry but in the table, it shows like this

> 590380500

but I want it like this
590
380
500
I have tried to use

```
<div>{{value}}<br></div>
```

but it wont work.. anyone have an idea how it should work